# What to look for in a good french press?

Tags: equipment, french-press

I am looking to buy a french press as my moka is now a little damaged. The handle melted because of misuse and now I have to handle the moka with oven gloves. It is a hassle to do, I spilled coffee all over the ground.

The price range for french press is insane. A functioning french press can be bought from [£6.90](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nerthus-French-Press-Coffee-Maker/dp/B08554TV6T/ref=sr_1_46?crid=1U32V0RCVXA3G&dchild=1&keywords=french%20press%20coffee%20maker&qid=1603809374&sprefix=french%20%2Caps%2C197&sr=8-46) to [£25.99](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Groenenberg-Cafeti%C3%A8re-Stainless-Double-Walled-Replacement/dp/B086LKQ7WV/ref=sr_1_21?crid=1U32V0RCVXA3G&dchild=1&keywords=french%20press%20coffee%20maker&qid=1603809427&sprefix=french%20%2Caps%2C197&sr=8-21). It is a lot of money to pay if there is no difference. **So, what makes a good french press?**

I have more specific questions at hand.

- Usually models whose external design is metallic rather than plastic are more expensive. Does the external mesh affect the taste or healthiness of the coffee? How durable is the external mesh compared to the glass, i.e., would I expect to use a metallic french press longer?
- One model displays [cork on top](https://www.amazon.co.uk/BODUM-1923-109s-Plunger-Cafetiere-Transparent/dp/B078VM925J/ref=sxts_sxwds-deals?crid=1U32V0RCVXA3G&cv_ct_cx=french%20press%20coffee%20maker&dchild=1&keywords=french%20press%20coffee%20maker&pd_rd_i=B078VM925J&pd_rd_r=0777da5f-ffb8-408c-ab1a-6c9459710109&pd_rd_w=IPEC1&pd_rd_wg=uSR28&pf_rd_p=f19c6998-9ae0-4218-a0ea-903d8ebdc53c&pf_rd_r=CKT6CJP26J5BKM2GJ6X0&psc=1&qid=1603809427&sprefix=french%20%2Caps%2C197&sr=1-3-639fa736-8ebd-4159-8516-a629dca5da33). Does it have any affect?
- Some models come with extra filters. How frequent do I need to change filters and why do I need to change them?
- Cheaper models don't even mention about stainless steel. How does stainless steel impact the coffee maker from health, taste and durability perspective.

I apologise if such questions are out of topic. I would be happy to ask all these specific question separately if it is considered too broad for this SE.

Thanks!